How can I prevent autofill in form fields while developing an Angular project?
I'm currently developing a web application using Angular, and I've encountered an issue with autofill in form fields. Whenever I test my forms, especially in Chrome, the browser autofills some of the fields with saved information, which is interfering with my testing process and it distract user to fill the correct data .
I've tried setting the autocomplete attribute to "off" on my form fields, but it doesn't seem to work reliably. Is there a more effective way to prevent autofill in Angular? Is there a more reliable way to prevent autofill in Angular Reactive forms? Are there any Angular-specific techniques or best practices for handling this issue? I'm open to any suggestions or insights. Thank you for your help!

"I've tried setting the autocomplete attribute to 'off'" This should normally work, can you include the browser where you are encountering this issue?

Can you show your reactive forms setup ?

Just add an attribute name with a different value in the input fields. In the below example, I have added name="firstname".
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>First Name:</mat-label>
  <input matInput name="firstname" autocomplete="off">
</mat-form-field>

Moreover, if you are using the same field multiple times in your project, you can change it, like name="fname". Try using unique field names so they do not repeat.

Since you're using Angular Reactive Forms, you can control the autofill behavior programmatically within your component code. After initializing the form, you can reset the values of the form controls to empty strings to prevent autofill.
Sample code:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-form',
  templateUrl: './my-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-form.component.css']
})
export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      // Define your form controls here
    });

    this.resetForm();
  }

  resetForm(): void {
    // Reset form controls to empty strings to prevent autofill
    this.myForm.reset();
  }
}

